# Capping off electrical outlet in a series

Tags: electrical

After successfully capping off an electrical outlet, I turned the breaker back on and the adjacent outlet works fine but the next outlet and light switch in the series will not work. Why is that? What did I do wrong?

Comment: How many cables came into the box for the outlet you capped off? Can you post photos of the inside of that box?

Comment: Did you take a photo of the original before disconnection? Before smartphones, I used to stick labels (numbers worked well) on each wire and draw a diagram... Then do a diagram of what I was changing to...

Comment: I apologize for the delay in adding the photo. I'm afraid that I'm technologically challlenged. My outlets are on a parallel circuit so there were 5 wires so I capped off the neutrals together, the hot together, and the ground. It appears to me that the outlet and switch that aren't working are furthest away from the power source or breaker box but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with my situation. I must be missing something or just overlooked something. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Capped off electrical outlet. This outlet is part of a 4 outlet, 1 double pole light switch on a parallel circuit. I don't know if it makes a difference but the capped off outlet is 2nd in line on the parallel circuit. When I turned the breaker back on, the 1st and 3rd outlet worked fine but the 4th outlet and light switch (located at end of the circuit) did not.